# How to select a value in second dropdown based on value selected in first dropdown? both values are coming from the database using same list

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I am using two drop-downs same data in list data coming from database. Suppose if I select name in first drop-down then this particular will not show in second drop-down.

Example, value in First drop-down is:

```
David
Georj
Michel
```

If I select Michel. Then value should be in Second drop-down are :

```
David
Georj
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Which language? which tool kit? code example?

Comment: He has tagged it as Javascript @Serge

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @JoeyPinto as well as java

Answer (score 0):

Use simple javascript to do this.

Create an array by using

```
var array=[];
```

Add elements to it using the push operator and remove using pop iterator

Then iterate the array using a for loop and use this snippet to add a element 'i' dynamically to the select list

```
select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

 var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = i;
opt.innerHTML = i;
select.appendChild(opt);
```

Use

```
 select.innerHTML=null;
```

to clear

Comment: Could you please help me in struts and employeelist is Arraylist type.Could you please help how can I implement